# How to use project file in the pods folder's file

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, cocoapods

I have a project and i added Pods in it and run project with `project-name.xworkspace` file but now i need to use a file in the pods file but, when i import this file into the pods file it show error "File could not found".
Please solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please be more specific. What is the name of the pod you where attempting to import? Can you post the line of code you used to import?

Comment: Can you post the contents of your Podfile? Does the podfile include the line "workspace 'project-name'"? Did you run pod install OR pod update?

Comment: I have project and i added pods and it add another project in it now I want to add some file to this new pods and use in it but I'm getting this error.

Comment: Did you get the answers?